# Python 3- Writing a program that reads number from a file, months names wont print, errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help getting my code to work correctly. For some reason it wont display the month names and its giving me a error for calculating the total rainfall

line 58, in totalRainfall
    return sum(rainfall)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Here is my assignment
Write a program that read the total rainfall for each of the 12 months into a list.  The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts

```
def monthsList():
       #creates a list of the months
    monthList = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March','April','May', 'June','July', 'August','September','October', 'November', 'December']
    return monthList



def totalRainfall(rainfall):
#gets sum of all rainfall
    return sum(rainfall)



def averageRainfall(rainfall):
#gets the sum of rainfall and divides by 12 to get the average
    return sum(rainfall)/12



def maxRainfall(monthList):
#finds the max index number in monthList
# adds one so it wont start at 0
    return monthList.index(max(monthList))+1



def minRainfall(monthsList):
#finds the min index number in monthList
# adds one so it wont start at 0
    return monthList.index(min(monthList))+1

def main():


inFile = open('program9.txt', 'r')

rainfall = [] # set rainfall to an empty list

lineRead = inFile.readline()       # Read first record
while lineRead != '':              # While there are more records
   words = lineRead.split()        # Split the records into substrings
   rainfall = float(words[0])
   print(format(rainfall, '.2f'))

   lineRead = inFile.readline()    # Read next record

totR=totalRainfall(rainfall) #assigns totR to the rainfall total
avgR=averageRainfall(rainfall) # assigns avgR to rainfall average
maxR=maxRainfall(rainfall) # assigns maxR to the maxrainfall
minR=minRainfall(rainfall) #assigns minR to minrainfall 

print('The total Rainfall for the year was: ',format(totR, ',.2f'), sep='')
print('The average Rainfall for the year was: ', format(avgR, ',.2f'), sep='')
print('The month with highest rainfall was:',maxR)
print('The month with lowest rainfall was:',minR)

inFile.close() # Close file
# End of the main function 

main()
```

the text file is:

1.89

1.99

2.14

2.51

5.03

3.81

1.97

2.31

2.91

3.97

2.68

2.44

Comment: You initially had `rainfall = []`, then you did `rainfall = float(words[0])` which redefined rainfall from a list to a float. So `totalRainfall` got a floating point number, instead of a list.

Comment: I recommend learning how to use a debugger to go through your code line-by-line. You can then check the type and value of each variable as it runs through your code.

Comment: Almost all of these functions are superfluous, they only make the program more complex. Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: thank you for the tip, do you have a debugger recommendation?

Comment: i will definitely go fix the names, thank you. Im not quiet sure how i would fix the the functions. Could you tell me what you mean by them being superfluous?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing "rainfall = float(words[0])" with " rainfall.append(float(words [0])) ".